# How to conditionally execute "copy-dependencies" before my custom Maven Mojo?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have forked the Maven Dependency plugin and created a new Mojo, let's call it mojo-a. I would like mojo-a to check whether the copy-dependencies Mojo has already been executed in the current build lifecycle. If it has, mojo-a should do nothing; if not, mojo-a should automatically invoke copy-dependencies.

How can I programmatically ensure that copy-dependencies is run before mojo-a, without requiring the user to explicitly execute copy-dependencies when it hasn't been run yet?

I'm looking for a way to manage this dependency within the Mojo's execution context, possibly by checking the build context or session information.

Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First why have you done that ... and for what purpose? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Please describe the problem?

Comment: Whatever you a trying to do, it sounds like a wrong way. Could you describe the original problem that you are trying to solve?